# layout management in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an app for all screen resolutions. So for that, according to the documentation I have created a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for medium, high, and extra high density screens.

For example:

`res/layout-normal/my_layout.xml`             **// layout for normal screen size ("default")**

`res/layout-small/my_layout.xml`       **// layout for small screen size**

`res/layout-large/my_layout.xml`       **// layout for large screen size**

`res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml`      **// layout for extra large screen**

Now while running my app in different device what I notice that some of the devices with different screen resolution take the layout from the same resource directories i.e. layout-normal, and example of such devices are:

HVGA (320 x 480)

WQVGA 400 (240 x 400)

WVGA (480 x 800)

WXGA (720 x 1280)

Due to the use of layout from the same resource directories i.e. layout-normal it very difficult for me to manage the space between the UI for all devices as they take the same layout. Because if I manage the layout for HVGA then it doesn't look good in other, because of resolution.

So is there any way to solve this problem? Please help me to solve this out.

Answer (score 0):

Dont prepare xml for each layouts. just make images for all (ldp, mdpi , hdpi) with same name and put in this different folder as per size.

```
ldpi : 240X320
mdpi : 320X480
hdpi : 480X800
```

And give permission in android Android Manifest file.

```
 <supports-screens android:normalScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

i am apply this way to make universal app in android.it will work fine, try like this way..

Comment: yep...i have done this also...but no good result..its works but for pages it does'nt work for all pages..

Answer (score 0):

@hasMukh has pointed the right direction, but if you want the layouts for those 4 devices to be more precise. I suggest you to use the "layout-density-resolution" format for layout folder naming. As an example,

for HVGA(320x480) layout folder should be "layout-hdpi-480x320"
for WQVGA(240x400) layout folder should be "layout-ldpi-400x240"
for WVGA(480x800) layout folder should be "layout-mdpi-800x480"
for WXGA(720x1280) layout folder should be "layout-mdpi-1280x720"

This method is only good if you are planning to target specific few devices..and you can keep only one drawabale folder and use dp values for layouts.

Answer (score -2):

i have the same problem, i used another approach.
get device height/width :

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE); // the results will be higher than using the activity context object or the getWindowManager() shortcut
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

and check the device height/width according to that i used layout like

```
if(screenWidth == 320 || screenHeight== 480){
        setContentView(R.layout.test_320_480);
    }else if(screenWidth == 240 || screenHeight == 320){
        setContentView(R.layout.test_240_320);
    }else if(screenWidth == 480 || screenHeight == 800 || screenHeight == 854){
        setContentView(R.layout.test_480_800);
    }
```

use the same id for each controls in the layout for same screen.i hv put all layout in layout folder and it works for me.

Comment: yep...i know this way we can do it...but is this not possible to do any other way

Comment: documentation says clearly to use qualifaiers as above, not such strange combinations.