# How to remove ldpi Support from device?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to remove ldpi support from Android device? I don't want to display anything in ldpi supported devices. How to do that?

I change my manifest file:
In manifest I done following changes:

```
Screen Support 
android:smallScreens="false";
```

Comment: but steel got in ldpi.how to do it?

Comment: why do you hate people with ldpi ?

Answer (score 4):

Code found on Android Developer site, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html).

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens - except ldpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens - except ldpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens - except ldpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens - except ldpi -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Comment: i could not get android:requiresSmallestWidthDp option in my support-screens.Well Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest add this after uses-permission

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"/>
```

or check this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800554/1838457